# Pong Game in java

Tags: java

I am making a game in java called pong, which I am sure everyone knows what that's game is. I have it all working good, but now I want to put block up top for the ball to hit, that I have set up already. What I am looking for is when the ball makes contact with the block, I want the block to disappear, but I am not really sure how to do so

```
g.setColor(Color.blue);
g.fillRect(block1X, 250, 150, 15);
```

The code above is the block

```
if(ballX >= block1X && ballX <= block1X + 150 && ballY >= 240)
   ballYSpeed = -7;

else if(ballX <= block1X && ballX <= block1X + 150 && ballY <= 270) 
   ballYSpeed = 7;
```

The code above is the if and else if for when the ball makes contact from above the block and from below the block. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick approach (far not the best) could be in this exact situation is to track the state of your block with a boolean.

initializte it true

```
boolean isAlive = true;
```

And your drawing should depend on this:

```
if(isAlive){
    //drawing block here
}
```

On you collision set `isAlive` false and it wont be drawn anymore.

However its a poor solution, you should creata a `Block` class and a List or array of Block in your some kind of Game class, populate your list with blocks, update/render them by looping through all of them.

This could be a very simple Block class

```
public class Block{

private int x;
private int y;
    public Block(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    //This is how you draw it
    public void draw(){
    }

    //If needed for example a moving block
    public void update(){
    }
}
```

In your class where game play happening you can define an ArrayList and populate with blocks.
`ArrayLis<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();`

In your game loop you can draw like:

```
for(Block block: blocks){
    block.draw();
}
```

And finally either you can define a boolean wheter the block is alive or not, or just simply remove the specific block from the list. Note that, to test collision you have to loop through the blocks and test them one by one.